# How can I show my website Favicon across all browsers?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, favicon

Currently my website favicon only works in Firefox. It does not show in Chrome, IE or Edge. In chrome it only shows a globe.

My site is http://www.photogrfr.com

Here is my code that I setup:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ 'favicon-144x144.png' | asset_url }}">
```

What is weird is that it's working on all browsers just fine on a new page that I recently built found here: https://www.photogrfr.com/pages/learn-more

But not on any other pages on my domain.

[image: Bolt Favicon on Google Chrome]

I have tried clearing cache in the Chrome settings, using a pc/browser that I have never used before.

I have also tried using a 16x16 PNG and ICO file.

Nothing seems to be working. The code in the learn-more page that I built is the same in my Shopify theme.liquid as well.

[image: Favicon not working]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The link to the icon is missing at http://www.photogrfr.com/, but it is there at your second URL. I don't know where Firefox is pulling it from.

Comment: @tromgy that's because it isn't hosted at photogrfr.com. Piping it through `asset_url` gives https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/t/15/assets/favicon-144x144.png?v=15586110514870709985, which resolves. For some reason Chrome doesn't render it as the favicon though... I'm guessing due to some non-standard PNG data in the image itself that Firefox is more forgiving of? Chrome usually works fine with PNG favicons.

Comment: I added the PNG file to the assets library in Shopify. Also I tried a .ico filetype. I also tried using a Favicon generator and also created one in photoshop. Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by adding the code to the top of the  section. Even though it was between the tags, for some reason putting it as the first line fixed it.